# angular primeng how to display context menu on left click

Tags: angular2-directives, primeng-datatable

i am new to angular2/primeng.

How to show the primeng context menu on left click instead of the default right click inside a datatable?

thanks

Comment: There is no such option available as of now, for this either you have to do chnages in the library's components or you have to create custom one

Answer (score 3):

**Since version 6.1.4 of PrimeNG it can be done with `triggerEvent` property.**

*On the template:*

```html
<img #targetImage2 src="assets/img/vejo_trabalhos_bonitos.jpg" alt="Test image">
<p-contextMenu [target]="targetImage2" [model]="contextMenuItems" [appendTo]="'body'" triggerEvent="click"></p-contextMenu>
```

*On the component:*

```js
contextMenuItems: MenuItem[];

constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.contextMenuItems = [
    { label: 'Edit', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil', command: event => this.displayMessage(event.item.label) },
    { label: 'Export', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-external-link', command: event => this.displayMessage(event.item.label) },
    { label: 'Delete', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash', command: event => this.displayMessage(event.item.label) }
  ];
}

displayMessage(action: string): void {
  this.messageService.add({severity: 'info', summary: `"${action}" action clicked!`});
}
```

**But if one wants to display the context menu on both left and right mouse button events. It can be done too.**

*On the template:*

```html
<img #targetImage src="assets/img/vejo_trabalhos_bonitos.jpg" alt="Test image" (click)="onLeftMouseClick($event,contextMenu)">
<p-contextMenu #contextMenu [target]="targetImage" [model]="contextMenuItems" [appendTo]="'body'"></p-contextMenu>
```

*On the component:*

```js
contextMenuItems: MenuItem[];

constructor(private messageService: MessageService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.contextMenuItems = [
    { label: 'Edit', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil', command: event => this.displayMessage(event.item.label) },
    { label: 'Export', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-external-link', command: event => this.displayMessage(event.item.label) },
    { label: 'Delete', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash', command: event => this.displayMessage(event.item.label) }
  ];
}

displayMessage(action: string): void {
  this.messageService.add({severity: 'info', summary: `"${action}" action clicked!`});
}

onLeftMouseClick(event: MouseEvent, contextMenu: ContextMenu): void {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  contextMenu.show(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider why you would want to change the default like that.  Right clicking is pretty much the universal way that people expect Context Menus to work.  As Pardeep said, other than rooting around in the code, you wouldn't be able to change that.